# Caption at left side of the table

Tags: tables, captions

How can I display the table caption at the left side?

Thank you,
[image]

Comment: Have you tried the [sidecap](https://ctan.org/pkg/sidecap) package?

Comment: Alternatively, you can put the caption inside a minipage.

Answer (score 4):

with use of package `sidecup`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[leftcaption]{sidecap} % <-- added
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{SCtable}[][ht]
\caption{The caption text over multiple lines on outer side of table}%
\label{tab:side}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
        bla & blu & lbll \\
        \midrule
        bla & djfgkdjf jkdfg  dfkgjd kjgkd fkgjdkfgj kdjfgkj & lbll \\
        bla & blu & lbll \\
        bla & blu & lbll \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{SCtable}
\lipsum[2]
\begin{table}[ht]
\caption{The caption text over multiple lines on the top of table}%
\label{tab:top}
\centering
    \begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
        bla & blu & lbll \\
        \midrule
        bla & djfgkdjf jkdfg  dfkgjd kjgkd fkgjdkfgj kdjfgkj & lbll \\
        bla & blu & lbll \\
        bla & blu & lbll \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{table}
\lipsum[3]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use `minipage` environments to place content side-by-side. The `\caption` can be in a different `minipage` as the `tabular` environment. Using the optional argument of `minipage` you then can align both at the top.
For this to work well I recommend to set the `\abovecaptionskip` locally to zero to avoid some unwanted space above the caption. Also the `tabular` minipage should start with `\vspace*{0pt}` to have an zero-height line there for the alignment.

Here an example code with `minipage`s and then a second way using the `adjustbox` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum

\begin{table}

\begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}%
    \caption{The caption text over multiple lines}%
\end{minipage}\hfill
\begin{minipage}[t]{.75\textwidth}\vspace*{0pt}%
    \begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
        bla & blu & lbll \\
        \midrule
        bla & djfgkdjf jkdfg  dfkgjd kjgkd fkgjdkfgj kdjfgkj & lbll \\
        bla & blu & lbll \\
        bla & blu & lbll \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{minipage}


\end{table}

\lipsum


\begin{table}

\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=[t]{.2\textwidth},valign=t}
    \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}%
    \caption{The caption text over multiple lines}%
\end{adjustbox}\hfill
\begin{adjustbox}{minipage=.75\textwidth,valign=t}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}\toprule
        bla & blu & lbll \\
        \midrule
        bla & djfgkdjf jkdfg  dfkgjd kjgkd fkgjdkfgj kdjfgkj & lbll \\
        bla & blu & lbll \\
        bla & blu & lbll \\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{adjustbox}

\end{table}

\lipsum


\end{document}
```

Both figures look like this.

[image: Result]

Note that you can adjust the widths by changing `.2\textwidth` and `.75\textwidth`. Both should add up to less then `1.0\textwidth` and there should not be a line break between the `minipages` so that both build a single line.