# How to make a table caption appear on the left of the table

Tags: tables, captions, tabu, sidecap

I'd like to put a caption on the left of the table (not meaning text is left-aligned) like this:

[image]

```
\begin{table}[t]
\caption{caption left}
\label{tab:1}
\centering
    \begin{tabu} to 1 \linewidth{|X[2.2,l] |X[3.0,l] |X[0.65,c] |X[0.65,c]| X[0.65,c]|} \hline
    A & B & C & D & E\\\hline\hline
    A & B & C & D & E\\ \hline
    \end{tabu}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Caption at left side of the table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/394119/caption-at-left-side-of-the-table)

Comment: @Roland Thanks, but can't I use tabu?

Comment: i don't think SCtable cares what you put inside, even \includegraphics.

Comment: Use of `tabu` is deprecated. Package is buggy and not maintained. Also has additional problems with new version of LaTeX. In your case rather use `tabularx`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don´t see any reason why it does not work with `\tabu`.

Here with the [seond answer using minipage](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/406468/224762):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{table}
    
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.2\textwidth}
        \setlength{\abovecaptionskip}{0pt}%
        \caption{The caption text over multiple lines}%
    \end{minipage}\hfill
    \begin{minipage}[t]{.75\textwidth}\vspace*{0pt}%
        \begin{tabu} to 1 \linewidth{|X[2.2,l] |X[3.0,l] |X[0.65,c] |X[0.65,c]| X[0.65,c]|} \hline
    A & B & C & D & E\\ \hline\hline
    A & B & C & D & E\\ \hline
    \end{tabu}
    \end{minipage}  
    
\end{table}
    
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I was trying with SCtable, but SCtable always moves to the right, not left. Don't know why..

Comment: with `\usepackage[leftcaption]{sidecap}`

Comment: Thanks! It worked.

Comment: You might want to use \raggedright or \sloppy with narrow captions.